# "Wordpress MultiSite Through Azure, Additional sites all say "The resource .... is unavailable

Tags: php, wordpress, azure, subdomain, multisite

So I'm working through windows azure to make a Wordpress multisite (sorry if this question seems obvious,I just can't seem to find any documentation or videos on this being done before, though I'm sure it has.)

I've set up my Wordpress multi-site through windows azure portal gallery.I have the Network admin dash board. So I'm confident I've done the first steps correctly in converting a Wordpress into a Multisite. I set up the network as sub-domains.

The issue is whenever I make a new website through the multisite network admin dashboard and try to edit it i just get "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

my question is do i need to custom map domains in order for this to work? or do i need to be adding another step with azure.

How can I just create the Multi-sites without having custom domains for each one if this is the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you setup the network as ***sub-domains*** you have to have a custom domain for the website and point your subdomains. About how to do that, see [Adding custom domains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-php-convert-wordpress-multisite#adding-custom-domains). Otherwise, you could choose ***sub-directories*** as the type of multisite network instead.

For more information on *sub-domain* vs *sub-directory* setups see the [Types of multisite network](https://codex.wordpress.org/Before_You_Create_A_Network#Types_of_multisite_network) article on the WordPress Codex.

---

However, according to the error you aforementioned, seems there is a mistake in `web.config` file WordPress generated. You can find the correct one in following threads:

[How to set-up Wordpress Multi-sites on Azure using sub-directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30804149/how-to-set-up-wordpress-multi-sites-on-azure-using-sub-directories)

[getting 404 error on admin panel for sub-directory multisite on a sub-domain in wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17298702/getting-404-error-on-admin-panel-for-sub-directory-multisite-on-a-sub-domain-in)

Comment: THANK YOU!! the wp-config settings from wordpress were wrong somehow. However the link you sent me fixed the issue. Thank you!